# How to create list bullets in an operator's class description? (see example)

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I noticed this description for the measure tool. How do you create list bullets in an operator's class description?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tool description**

The bulleted list is a description of the measureit ruler tool, the source of which can be found in *`startup/bl_ui/space_toolsystem_toolbar.py`*

```
@ToolDef.from_fn
def ruler():
    def description(_context, _item, km):
        if km is not None:
            kmi_add = km.keymap_items.find_from_operator("view3d.ruler_add")
            kmi_remove = km.keymap_items.find_from_operator("view3d.ruler_remove")
        else:
            kmi_add = None
            kmi_remove = None
        return tip_(
            "Measure distance and angles.\n"
            "\u2022 %s anywhere for new measurement.\n"
            "\u2022 Drag ruler segment to measure an angle.\n"
            "\u2022 %s to remove the active ruler.\n"
            "\u2022 Ctrl while dragging to snap.\n"
            "\u2022 Shift while dragging to measure surface thickness"
        ) % (
            kmi_to_string_or_none(kmi_add),
            kmi_to_string_or_none(kmi_remove),
        )
    return dict(
        idname="builtin.measure",
        label="Measure",
        description=description,
        icon="ops.view3d.ruler",
        widget="VIEW3D_GGT_ruler",
        keymap="3D View Tool: Measure",
    )
```

The bullet is character \u2022.  The associated shortcuts are gleaned from the respective keymaps.

**Operator description classmethod.**

Find link

[image]

Operators can now have multi line tooltips. Here I've put the above description into the simple operator template

```
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def description(cls, context, event):
        return (
                "Measure distance and angles.\n"
                "\u2022 %s anywhere for new measurement.\n"
                "\u2022 Drag ruler segment to measure an angle.\n"
                "\u2022 %s to remove the active ruler.\n"
                "\u2022 Ctrl while dragging to snap.\n"
                "\u2022 Shift while dragging to measure surface thickness"
                ) % ("Foo", "Bar")        
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
```

Comment: I just realized I forgot to say thank you. I guess I forgot because I was too excited to try it out. Anyway, that's so much for the detailed example and for the great help in general.

Comment: Cheers, appreciated. It's the non accepted, non-voted, non-commented (_ie total ignorance_) ones that really get the goat. Esp when used in OP's next question _I wrote this code...._